# Google <title> not appear correctly

Tags: html, title

I'm investigating since two weeks why Google doesn't print the exact same `<title>` tag placed in my html.

Here is my code in html:

```
<title>30.1 Restaurant | Bar and restaurant in Madrid</title>
```

And google print it as:

```
Bar and restaurant in Madrid: 30.1 Restaurant
```

Same if I replace the `|` by a `-`

I also noticed in Safari the title tab skip the number and only show:

```
Restaurant | Bar and restaurant in Madrid
```

There is some restriction in number in title tags?

Comment: How about providing your actual title code?

Comment: google CHROME not google

Comment: Try reloading the page and updating your browser it works fine on my browser.

Comment: On Google chrome it works fine. Un safari sometime it works sometime not. But the real problem is in Google search results !